# Strange behaviour of sql statement in Yii 1.3

Tags: php, yii

I have one controller, and I use it's result as src of image in image constructor method and here it's code:

```
        static function getCamByClassIdForAdmin($id)
        {
            $connection=Yii::app()->db;
            $command=$connection->createCommand("Select Cam1,Cam2 from crd_classes where id={$id}");
            $camReader=$command->query();
            $camList=$command->queryAll();
//I do such strange things to get result, because when I tried return $camList[0]['Cam1'] or to use indexes in constructor of image it says that it has undefined offset - 0 for some reason
            $result="";
            foreach ($camList as $cam) 
            {
                foreach ($cam as $current => $currentValue) 
                {
                    if ($current=='Cam1')
                    {
                        $result=$currentValue;
                    }
                }
            }
            $camId=$result;
            return $result;
    };
```

And here is how I use it in image constructor:

```
        'value' => function($data, $row) {
            return CHtml::image(
                //LessonsController::getCamByClassId($data->Lesson_ID)[0]['Cam1'],
                LessonsController::getCamByClassIdForAdmin($data->Lesson_ID),
                "default image",
                array('width'=>195, 'height'=>110)
            );
        }
```

So it returns the result, I expect. Next I want to use result of this query in one more query, so I modified controller code like this.

```
static function getCamByClassIdForAdmin($id)
{
    $connection=Yii::app()->db;
    $command=$connection->createCommand("Select Cam1,Cam2 from crd_classes where id={$id}");
    $camReader=$command->query();
    $camList=$command->queryAll();
    $result="";
    foreach ($camList as $cam) 
    {
        foreach ($cam as $current => $currentValue) 
        {
            if ($current=='Cam1')
            {
                $result=$currentValue;
            }
        }
    }
    $camId=$result;
    $connection1=Yii::app()->db;
    $command1=$connection1->createCommand("Select cam from cam_names where id={$camId}");
    $camReader1=$command1->query();
    $camList1=$command1->queryAll();    
    return $result;
}
```

And I receive exception that :

```
The SQL statement executed was: Select cam from cam_names where id=
```

So, `$camId` seems to be empty, however it is not. To check this I've added following code after `$camId=$result;`

```
ob_start();
var_dump($camId);
$result=ob_get_clean();
```

But still select statement is like it was empty.
Do you have any suggestions why can it behave itself like this?

**UPDATE**
tried this:

```
$result=$connection->createCommand("Select Cam1 from crd_classes where id={$id}")->queryScalar();
$resultCam=$connection->createCommand("Select cam from cam_names where id={$result}")->queryScalar();
```

This reduced code a lot. But mistake is the same

```
The SQL statement executed was: Select cam from cam_names where id=
```

**UPDATE1**
I even tried to  split them into two different methods.

```
static function getCamByClassIdForAdmin($id)
{
    $connection=Yii::app()->db;
    $result=$connection->createCommand("Select Cam1 from crd_classes where id={$id}")->queryScalar();
    return $result;
}
static function getCamNameByIdForAdmin($id)
{
    $connection=Yii::app()->db;
    $result=$connection->createCommand("Select cam from cam_names where id={$id}")->queryScalar();  
    return $result;
}
```

Strange behaviour remains:

```
        return CHtml::image(
            LessonsController::getCamByClassIdForAdmin($data->Lesson_ID),
            "default image",
            array('width'=>195, 'height'=>110)
        );
```

returns id of cam
but 
                return CHtml::image(
                    LessonsController::getCamNameByIdForAdmin(LessonsController::getCamByClassIdForAdmin($data->Lesson_ID)),
                    "default image",
                    array('width'=>195, 'height'=>110)
                );

says about mistake: The SQL statement executed was: Select cam from cam_names where id=
I even tried to make them public instead of static. Result is the same.

**UPDATE 2**
It looks like `$id` is not populated, however it is.Proof:

```
static function getCamNameByIdForAdmin($id)
{
    ob_start();
    var_dump($id);
    $result=ob_get_clean();
    /*$connection=Yii::app()->db;
    $result=$connection->createCommand("Select cam from cam_names where id={$id}")->queryScalar();*/    
    return $result;
}
```

returns:

```
string(3) "741
```

**UPDATE3**
tried `debug_zval_dump` instead of `var_dump`
I receive

```
string(3) "741" refcount(3)
```

In my src, so there is 2 more refs somewhere out of function. When I see into xdebug, I can tell more I hope.

Comment: this isn't a direct answer but why are you using queryAll?  is 'id' in crd_classes unique?  If so you could use $result = $connection->createCommand("Select Cam1from crd_classes where id={$id}")->queryScalar(); which should return just the one occurence of Cam1.

Comment: I'll check your answer later. Have another task now.

Comment: SO it looks like your $id isn't populated, as it isn't shown in the SQL.

Comment: OK try breaking down the createcommand and see what you get 1) $sql="Select cam from cam_names where id={$id}"; 2) var_dump($sql); 3) $result=$connection->createCommand($sql)->queryScalar();

Comment: dump of $sql shows Select cam from cam_names where id=123 but when I add queryScalar it returns same mistake.

Comment: so next step, change queryScalar to queryRow() and then dump out the results

Comment: Same result. Dump is ok when I use certain value instead of $id.

Comment: I think I would step through using XDEBUG to see where your variable is being corrupted.

Comment: I've compared two queries in one. If anyone ran into similar problem and finds the solution, youc can still inform me here. It'll be usefull.